# Finding on which port a given server is running within python program

Tags: python, linux, macos, networking, tcp

I am developing a python 3.11 program which will run on a few different servers and needs to connect to the local Redis server. On each machine the latter might run on a different port, sometimes the default 6379 but not always.

On the commandline I can issue the following command which on both my Linux and MacOS servers works well:

```
(base) bob@Roberts-Mac-mini ~ % sudo lsof -n -i -P | grep LISTEN | grep IPv4 | grep redis
redis-ser 60014            bob    8u  IPv4 0x84cd01f56bf0ee21      0t0    TCP *:9001 (LISTEN)
```

What's the better way to get the running port using python functions/libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you run your commands within a py script using the `os` library:

```
import os
cmd = 'ls -l' <-- change the command you want to run
os.system(cmd)
```

or else you could also use `subprocess` library as well:

```
import subprocess
print(subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-l']))
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Yes of course I could do that and parse the result. Just wondering if there's some library wrapping this in a more terse/robust way.

Comment: @RobertAlexander oh alright.. i'm sorry but i couldn't think of any other way than this.

Comment: @RobertAlexander Let me know if this helped or if you come across any other way :)